# Fill Array with div elements populated dynamically in codebehind. C#, javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a report populated as a table with a stringbuilder from the codebehind.  The first TD of every row is a checkbox, the id of each checkbox is assigned dynamically:

```
sb.Append("<td><input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll_" + i + "' name='chk_" + i + "' onclick='JavaScript: chkAll_click(this);' />&nbsp;</td>"
```

The aspx page uses a master page and

```
<asp:Content><div id='divMain'></div></asp:Content>
```

format other than a form to populate.  The problem I am running in to is that I am having trouble finding all the elements (or any actually) of the div to work with.  Here is the javascript I have been given.  (Team project at work, I was just assigned 1 task on the project so changing anything is not an option.)

```
function divBatchBuild_click() {
    debugger
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var visitList = '';

    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {

        if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            //alert(form.elements[i].id.toString());

            if (form.elements[i].checked == true && 
                form.elements[i].id != 'chkSelectAll') {

                var y = form.elements[i].id;
                //alert('id=' + y[1].toString());
                visitList = visitList + y[i].toString() + '|';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently this worked on a previous project, but when used with this report the process never goes inside the if statement.  Any help on what is going wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Colud you post a sample of what the final HTML looks like?  In particular the table.

Comment: You mean the html source of the table?

Comment: basically the final HTML as rendered by the browser. Mainly just the finaly divMain portion

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to first get the div, then get the elements in the div with the checkbox tagname. Something like:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divMain');
var elements = div.getElementsByTagName('checkbox');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
```